# Are there any differences between applying floor division and int() after dividing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems there are cases that the outputs are different between applying floor division and int() after dividing.
Could you explain me the reasons or show me concrete cases?

**Problem:**
int(a // b) is not equal to int(a / b)

**Situation:**
a and b are integer and 0 < a,b <= 1e18

**Setting:**
Python 3.4.3

**Note:**
I cannot list up concrete cases because they are made by online judge test and test cases are not public.

I hope your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concrete example (in Python 3.4.4 shell):

```
>>> int(99999999999999999/100000000000000000)
1
>>> 99999999999999999//100000000000000000
0
```

This happens when the result of the (mathematical) float division is very near to an integer so that the numerical float division result is rounded towards this integer.

Comment: Incidentally, I have changed the condition of Problem from a//b to int(a//b), but this question and answer are still valid.

Comment: @sam If `a` and `b` are integers then `a//b` is an integer therefore `a//b == int(a//b)`